# Error while processing route: todos undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm getting this error after the Displaying Model Data step while trying to follow the TodoMVC demo app on the Ember site (http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/getting-started/). My javascript code up to this point is:

```
window.Todos = Ember.Application.create();

Todos.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

Todos.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('todos', { path: '/' });
});

Todos.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('todo');
    }
});

Todos.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')
});

Todos.Todo.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Learn Ember.js',
    isCompleted: true
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: '...',
    isCompleted: false
},
{
    id: 3,
    title: 'Profit!',
    isCompleted: false
}
];
```

Comment: please show what error you are getting

Comment: The error should come with a stack trace. Perhaps there is little black triangle you can pull down to see it. It will show you the line on which you are trying to call an undefined function. By the way, the error mesage is correctly parsed as "Error while procesisng route: todos / undefined is not a function."

Answer (score 0):

I think your router.map is wrong. Try using it in this way -

```
Todos.Router.map(
        function () {
                this.resource('todos', { path: '/' }, function () {
                this.route('active');
                this.route('completed');
        });
    });
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the OP's question and how would it solve it?